# Why does fgets reads garbage after line?

Tags: c, string, io, fgets

Having this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFLEN 255

char *unspace(char *s)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\n')
    {
      s[count++] = s[i];
    }
    else
    {
      s[count++] = ' ';
      while (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t' || s[i] == '\n')
      {
        i++;
      }
      i--;
    }
  }
  s[count] = '\0';
  return s;
}

char *translate(char *s)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (
        (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') ||
        (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||
        (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') ||
        s[i] == '.' ||
        s[i] == ',' ||
        s[i] == '!' ||
        s[i] == '?' ||
        s[i] == ' ')
    {
      s[count++] = s[i];
    }
    else
    {
      while (
          (s[i] < 'a' || s[i] > 'z') &&
          (s[i] < 'A' || s[i] > 'Z') &&
          (s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') &&
          s[i] != '.' &&
          s[i] != ',' &&
          s[i] != '!' &&
          s[i] != '?' &&
          s[i] != ' ')
      {
        i++;
      }
      i--;
    }
  }
  s[count] = '\0';
  return s;
}

char *toUpper(char *str)
{
  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
    {
      str[i] -= 32;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

int main()
{
  // ON STRINGS WORKS CORRECTLY
  //   char s1[] = "Ahoj,      @$~ja^&k se ma<>s?";
  //   char s2[] = "{Ma}m       se $#$$## dobre!       dnes je     *&&33// stupnu.";

  // puts(unspace(toUpper(translate(s1))));
  // -> AHOJ, JAK SE MAS?
  // puts(unspace(toUpper(translate(s2))));
  // -> MAM SE DOBRE! DNES JE 33 STUPNU.

  FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  char buf[BUFLEN] = {0};

  while (fgets(buf, BUFLEN, fp))
  {
    puts(unspace(toUpper(translate(buf))));
  }
}
```

and this data file:

```
$ cat data.txt
Ahoj,      @$~ja^&k se ma<>s?   
{Ma}m       se $#$$## dobre!       dnes je     *&&33// stupnu.
```

I always get the output with garbage at the end:

```
$ ./a.out
AHOJ, JAK SE MAS? 2Y9CNP5V
MAM SE DOBRE! DNES JE 33 STUPNU.2Y9CNP5V

$ ./a.out
AHOJ, JAK SE MAS? Y.XHNPVU
MAM SE DOBRE! DNES JE 33 STUPNU.Y.XHNPVU

$ ./a.out
AHOJ, JAK SE MAS? 9WAGPAV
MAM SE DOBRE! DNES JE 33 STUPNU.9WAGPAV

$ ./a.out
AHOJ, JAK SE MAS? MP9SU
MAM SE DOBRE! DNES JE 33 STUPNU. MP9SU
```

The program correctly reads the line from file, but adds some random characters at the end. Why is that so? And how to get rid of that characters?

Comment: Because when you encounter a newline character, you enter a while loop where you no longer check for `\0`.

Comment: @Cheatah i dont get it. Newline is responsibily of fgets

Comment: @milanHrabos *Newline is responsibily of fgets* What does that mean?

Comment: I misread the code, but funnily the problem is still the same. In the `while` loop of `translate` you don't check for `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

In the translate function, add condition "`(s[i] != '\0') &&`" in the `while` loop.

So the loop becomes:

```
else                                                   
{                                                      
  while ((s[i] != '\0') &&                             
      (s[i] < 'a' || s[i] > 'z') &&
      (s[i] < 'A' || s[i] > 'Z') &&
      (s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') &&
      s[i] != '.' &&
      s[i] != ',' &&
      s[i] != '!' &&
      s[i] != '?' &&
      s[i] != ' ')
  {
    i++;                                               
  }
```